# Lyapunov analysis of marginally stable linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Before I start, I want to emphasize I'm dealing with **marginally** stable linear systems, so many theorems about stable systems simply do not apply.

Let $\dot{x} = Ax$ be a marginally stable. That is, for any $x(0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $\|x(t)\|_2 \leq M$ for all $t \geq 0$. This is equivalent to saying that all eigenvalues of $A$ have non-positive real part, and the eigenvalues with zero real part have $1 \times 1$ Jordan blocks. (I am particularly dealing with a matrix $A$ with real eigenvalues, and all but one eigenvalues are negative, and the the remaining (simple) eigenvalue is $0$.)

[This](https://lewisgroup.uta.edu/Lectures/Lyapunov%20stab%20open%20loop.pdf) manuscript states $A$ is marginally stable if and only if there exists $Q \geq 0, P >0$ such that $$A^TP + PA = -Q.$$

My question is, is there a procedure to find such $Q, P$?

Edit: The linked manuscript has incorrect statements. @user1551 cleared everything up in their answer.

Comment: What if $Q \geq 0$ and $Q$ has a 0 eigenvalue?

Comment: @user1551 I think Spencer Kraisler is referring to Theorem. SISL for LTI CT Systems. on page 9. Finding $Q\geq0$ and $P>0$ such that $A^\top P+P\,A=-Q$ does indeed imply SISL. But that theorem does not state for any $Q\geq0$ one would be able to to find such a $P>0$. Also that theorem also does not state that $P$ should be unique.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Ah thank you for pointing that out. I suppose my new question is, how can I find $Q, P$ satisfying that equation. I updated the question.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Would you know of a proof of this claim? I cannot seem to find one anywhere, only for stable systems.

Comment: @user1551 I am referring to page 9. Let $Q \geq 0$. Then $\dot{x}=Ax$ is marginally stable iff the symmetric matrix $P$ that solves $A^TP + PA = -Q$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the theorem (on p.9 of the document) that you referred to:

> **Theorem. SISL for LTI CT Systems.** Let $Q$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Then the system $\dot{x}=Ax$ is SISL (e.g. marginally stable) if and only if the (symmetric) matrix $P$ which solves the CT Lyapunov equation
> $$
> A^TP+PA=-Q
> $$
> is positive definite.

This theorem is wrong:

1. The matrix $P$ that solves the matrix equation is not always positive definite. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0},\,P=-I$ and $Q=0$. The $P$ in this counterexample is not even positive *semi*-definite.
2. The theorem statement is ambiguous. It does not specify whether the matrix equation is always solvable or not, given Lyapunov stability. In fact, the equation is not always solvable. E.g. when $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$, the sum $A^TP+PA$ is traceless. Hence the only positive semi-definite matrix $Q$ that this sum can be equal to is zero.

I have not any training in control theory, but I find the definitions of marginal stability in the literature (not just in the linked document) rather unclear. While all definitions (correctly) require the eigenvalues of $A$ to have non-positive real parts, they do not agree on what happens on the imaginary axis. The authors of the linked document seem to require that all eigenvalues of $A$ on the imaginary axis, if any, to be simple, but they do not require $A$ to have at least one eigenvalue on the imaginary axis. In contrast, on p.7 of this [handout](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/218/CDS270-I_Lecture1.pdf) by Eugene Lavretsky, marginal stability is defined (more reasonably, I believe) as “stable but not asymptotically stable”. For the system $\dot x=Ax$, this means that on the imaginary axis, (1) there is at least one eigenvalue of $A$, and (2) repeated eigenvalues are allowed, but these eigenvalues must be *semi*-simple. For some curious reason, while the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability) on marginal stability also defines marginal stability as “stable but not asymptotically stable”, in terms of eigenvalues, it somehow states that the eigenvalues on the imaginary axis must be *simple*. I think Wikipedia is erred here, because for every marginally stable system $\dot x=Ax$, the system $\dot x=\pmatrix{A\\ &A}x$ (where the length of the vector $x$ is doubled) should also be marginally stable.

Anyway, let us adhere to Eugene Lavretsky's definition of marginal stability. If $A$ is marginally stable, then by considering the real Jordan form of $A$, we have
$$
A=SA_1S^{-1}=S\,\underbrace{\pmatrix{B\\ &K}}_{A_1}\,S^{-1}
$$
for some stable matrix $B$ and non-empty skew-symmetric matrix $K$. It follows that the equation $A^TP+PA=-Q$ is equivalent to $A_1^TP_1+P_1A_1=-Q_1$ where $P_1=S^TPS$ and $Q_1=S^TQS$. This can be further rewritten as
$$
\pmatrix{B^T\\ &K^T}\underbrace{\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Y^T&Z}}_{P_1}+\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Y^T&Z}\pmatrix{B\\ &K}=-Q_1\tag{1}
$$
Since $K^TZ+ZK$ is traceless, the equation is solvable only if $Q_1$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{Q_2\\ &0}$ for some PSD matrix $Q_2$ of the same size as $B$. When this is the case, the general solution to $(1)$ is given by $P_1=\pmatrix{X\\ &Z}$ where $X$ is the unique PSD solution to $B^TX+XB=-Q_2$ and $Z$ is *any* symmetric matrix that commutes with $K$ (in particular, one may take $Z$ to be any positive/zero/negative multiple of the identity matrix). It follows that (1) both PSD and non-PSD solutions always exist, (2) the solutions are always *non-unique* even if $P$ is required to be positive definite, and (3) positive definite solutions exist if and only if $Q_2$ is positive definite.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this write-up! I'm making my way few it. I have a few questions. First, is an eigenvalue semi-simple iff all Jordan blocks associated with that eigenvalue are 1x1? Second, can you explain why $K$ is necessarily skew-symmetric? $B$ will contain the Jordan blocks of the eigenvalues with negative real part (hence stable). I guess $K$ contains the Jordan blocks with eigenvalues on imaginary axis. Why is $K$ skew-symmetric?

Thinking about it now, there can't be any way $K$ is skew-symmetric unless $K=0$, no?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler (1) Yes, the Jordan blocks for a semi-simple eigenvalue must be trivial (1x1), but there can be many of them. (2) We are talking about the *real Jordan form* of a real square matrix with complex eigenvalues. For a complex Jordan form, we have the eigenvalues on the diagonal, but for a real Jordan form, we have real numbers or real $2\times2$ matrices on the diagonal instead. A conjugate pair of eigenvalues $a\pm bi$ is represented by a real $2\times2$ matrix $\pmatrix{a&-b\\ b&a}$ (known as a rotation-dilation). When $a=0$, this $2\times2$ matrix becomes skew-symmetric.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, why do you assume $S$ is orthogonal, if I am not mistaken? Isn't an invertible yet non-orthogonal $S$ possible? If $S$ is non-orthogonal, then $P_1$ might not be symmetric.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler I haven't assumed that $S$ is orthogonal. When $P$ is symmetric and invertible, $S^TPS$ is symmetric if and only if $P$ is symmetric (as $(S^TPS)^T=S^TP^T(S^T)^T=S^TPS$).

Comment: Ah ofc, thank you for the help. I have one more question, if possible. Can you explain why $K^TZ+ZK$ being traceless implies $Q_1$ takes the form you wrote?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Since $K^TZ+ZK$ is traceless, the only negative semidefinite matrix that it can be equal to is zero. Hence $Q_1$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{Q_2&\ast\\ \ast&0}$. As $Q_1$ is PSD, the two off-diagonal sub-blocks must be zero. Hence $Q_1=\pmatrix{Q_2&0\\ 0&0}$.

Comment: Awesome. There is a surprisingly lack of resources on Lyapunov analysis of marginally stable linear systems, but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords. Do you know any resources that go more into this?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Sorry, I don't know any.

Answer (score 1):

It can be noted that a [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation), of the form

$$
A^\top P + P\,A = -Q, \tag{1}
$$

is special form of a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). Such equations can be solved by transforming it into a system of linear equation using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Using this it can be shown that $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$
\underbrace{\left(I \otimes A^\top + A^\top\!\otimes I\right)}_M\,\text{vec}(P) = -\text{vec}(Q), \tag{2}
$$

with $I$ the identity matrix of the same size as $A$.

There is only a unique solution for $P$ when $M$ nonsingular, which is the case when the spectra of $A^\top$ and $-A$ are disjoint. This is not the case when $A$ has eigenvalues at zero or complex conjugate eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. So in your case $M$ would be singular, because $A$ has one eigenvalue at zero. However, this still leaves the possibility of instead having zero or infinite solutions, depending of the value of $Q$.

One has infinitely many solution when $\text{vec}(Q)$ lies in the span of $M$. The corresponding infinite solutions for $\text{vec}(P)$ can be obtained by adding any linear combination of the null space of $M$ to a solution.

---

For example consider the following

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{3}
$$

which has one negative eigenvalue and one eigenvalue of zero. Plugging this $A$ into the expression for $M$ yields

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{4}
$$

A span for the above matrix is given by

$$
\text{span}(M) = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.
$$

Therefore, matrices $Q$ for which $(1)$ does have a solution using $(3)$ has to be of the form

$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & -a-b-c
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

However, $Q$ should be symmetric and positive semi-definite. So a possible matrix would be

$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -2 \\ -2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{5}
$$

A vector, $\text{vec}(P)=v$ that would solve $(2)$ using $(3)$ and $(5)$ is

$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The null space of $(4)$ is given by

$$
\text{null}(M) = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.
$$

Therefore, a possible positive definite matrix $P$ that solves $(1)$ using $(3)$ and $(5)$ is

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$